# Problem with nested class (Thymeleaf form) - Failed to convert property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem with a Thymeleaf form with a nested class. I'm working on Calorie Counter Application and when I'm trying to add a new FoodProduct to an existing meal I get an exception. FoodProduct is a class that handles the template of all FoodProduct i.e.: Apple, Chicken Breast, etc.

**FoodProduct class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "food_products")
public class FoodProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "proteins")
    private Double proteins;

    @Column(name = "fats")
    private Double fats;

    @Column(name = "carbohydrates")
    private Double carbohydrates;

    @Column(name = "calories")
    private Double calories;

  // ...
}
```

MealFoodProduct class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meals_food_products")
@IdClass(MealFoodProductPK.class)
public class MealFoodProduct {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id")
    private Meal meal;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "food_product_id")
    private FoodProduct foodProduct;

    @Column(name = "food_product_weight")
    private double weight;

  //...
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveMealFoodProduct}" th:object="${mealFoodProduct}" method="post">

    <div>
        <label>Product name</label>
        <div>
            <select th:field="*{foodProduct}">
                <option th:each="foodProduct : ${foodProducts}" th:text="${foodProduct}" th:value="${foodProduct.id}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Weight</label>
        <div>
            <input type="number" th:field="*{weight}" placeholder="Enter weight">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I confirm a form I have this exception and I have no idea, what's wrong:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'pl.sosinski.nutritioncounter.model.FoodProduct' for property 'foodProduct';
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'pl.sosinski.nutritioncounter.model.FoodProduct' for property 'foodProduct': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'pl.sosinski.nutritioncounter.model.FoodProduct' for property 'foodProduct'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'pl.sosinski.nutritioncounter.model.FoodProduct' for property 'foodProduct': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `foodProduct` selection code to the following, the problem will be fixed.

```html
<select th:field="*{foodProduct.id}">
    <option th:each="foodProduct : ${foodProducts}" 
            th:text="${foodProduct}" 
            th:value="${foodProduct.id}"></option>
</select>
```

`OR`

You need to indicate to your app how convert a `Id` of `FoodProduct` returned inside form (`String Type`) to a `FoodProduct` entity. For that you have to use a Converter.

```java
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StringToFoodProductConverter implements Converter<String, FoodProduct> {

    @Override
    public FoodProduct convert(String arg0) {
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(arg0);
        FoodProduct foodProduct = new FoodProduct();
        foodProduct.setId(id);
        return foodProduct;
    }
}
```